# React Konva JS L shape Drag and dragBoundFunc not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

I am creating a straightforward code that allows an object to move within two Rect elements in the shape of an "L." However, my current implementation only permits the thing to move upwards from the bottom of the second Rect to the top of the first Rect, but I am struggling to enable movement from left to right. Can anyone provide guidance and assistance with this issue?

Here is an example of the code

```
import { Layer, Stage, Rect, Line } from "react-konva";

export default function App() {
  const firstref = React.useRef();
  const secondref = React.useRef();
  const dragableref = React.useRef();
  const gap = 20;
  const handleDragBound = (pos) => {
    // Get the bounding client rectangles of the elements
    const firstRect = firstref.current.getClientRect();
    const secondRect = secondref.current.getClientRect();
    const draggableRect = dragableref.current.getClientRect();

    // Calculate the new x-coordinate for the draggable rectangle,
    // considering the gap on both sides of the `firstRect`.
    const newX = Math.max(
      firstRect.x + gap,
      Math.min(
        secondRect.x + secondRect.width - draggableRect.width - gap,
        pos.x
      )
    );

    // Calculate the new y-coordinate for the draggable rectangle,
    // considering the gap on both sides of the `firstRect`.
    const newY = Math.max(
      firstRect.y + gap,
      Math.min(
        secondRect.y + secondRect.height - draggableRect.height - gap,
        pos.y
      )
    );

    // Return the new coordinates as an object.
    return { x: newX, y: newY };
  };

  const onDragStart = () => {};
  const handleDragMove = (e) => {};
  return (
    <Stage width={800} height={800}>
      <Layer>
        <Rect fill="red" x={0} y={0} width={500} height={200} ref={firstref} />

        <Rect
          fill="red"
          x={0}
          y={200}
          width={200}
          height={300}
          ref={secondref}
        />
        <Rect
          fill="blue"
          x={225}
          y={75}
          width={50}
          height={100}
          draggable
          ref={dragableref}
          dragBoundFunc={handleDragBound}
          onDragStart={onDragStart}
          onDragMove={handleDragMove}
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
}
```

Blue Rect is moving top and bottom not left to right and right to left
Below is the screenshot of what I am trying to build
I appreciate your interest

[image: Blue Rect is moving top bottom not left to right and right to left]